# Android PayPal Error - Please make sure all fields have been entered

Tags: android

I have a problem in creating a working PayPal button in Sandbox environment.

After entering my email and password in the sandbox environment.

This is what I see...can u guys any idea let me know...

[image: I got this error...]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when trying my app on Android 4.1... I have finally downloaded the latest version of the paypal library (MPL) and it is now working perfectly well. :-)